# Adding filter expressions dynamically to an array

Tags: c#, linq

I have this example which creates 3 expressions and adds them to one array of expression. 
Now i'd like to know how to do the same in a loop, for a unknown number of expressions.

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filter1 = c => c.City.StartsWith("S");
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filter2 = c => c.City.StartsWith("M");
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filter3 = c => c.ContactTitle == "Owner";

Expression<Func<Product, bool>>[] filterExpressions = new Expression<Func<Product, bool>>[] { filter1, filter2, filter3 };
```

Comment: Add them or create them?

Comment: @Arion good question. TysHTTP - It's not clear where is that you're 'stuck' here. I'm guessing it's a `dynamic` nature of things in some way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a List instead of an Array:

```
var filterExpressions = new List<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>
    { filter1, filter2, filter3 };

filterExpressions.Add(c => c.Name.StartsWith("J"));
```

And then if you, for some reason, need to pass the list to a method that only takes an Array you can use the ToArray() method:

```
var filterExpressionsArray = filterExpressions.ToArray();
```

Comment: Working with expressions you'd think OP would know this - but I guess given the question as is, this is the only answer that can be given at this point.

Comment: Sorry, i already fixed it some other way. I guess i just forgot how a list could help me here. I updated my code to List.ToArray(). Thanks!